# Angular2 - show data before load from http

Tags: angular

i have a problem with asynchronous loading data from server. In view are no any data because rendering is before load. 
Here is my code:
app.component.ts:

```
    user: User = new User()
    ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser(1).then(usr => {
      this.user = usr;
    }).catch((error: any) => {

    });
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
```

I thought that the data would change dynamically. Where is problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you try `<p>{{user?.name}}</p>`?

Comment: Yes, result is same. I dont see user name

Comment: Try to log the `this.user` after assignment in async call and show us the content

Comment: Did you change the `DetectionStrategy` in this\parent component?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, just wanted to point that was not exactly the issue here as in dupe suggestion. If you check the comment in below answer by OP. Data structure was changed, so apparently `user` no longer had property `name` ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 yeah, that'll do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use the elvis operator this might help

```
<p>{{user?.name}}</p>
```

Or may even try to make use of ngIf

```
<div *ngIf = "user">
    user.name
</div>
```

Comment: This is not good solution. I dont see user name. I created service for store user and getter and setter method a i put breakpoint to get set, first call get method and than set method

Comment: is the user getting logged in the component check that ?

Comment: I am sorry, problem is in data which i get from server. Data structure has been changed and i dont know. It works now

Comment: @bluray then why have you accepted this answer? It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
```

OR

```
<div *ngIf="user">
    {{user.name}}
</div>
```